# How can I check a CSS attribute on an <a> tag?

Tags: jquery

I need to check background-image if the image is enabled or disabled, i set some samples:

```
<a id="heart" href="" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 20px; height: 20px; font-size: 20px; background-image: url(http://localhost:1268/Selecciona/IMG/heart_disabled.png); background-repeat: no-repeat;"></a>

<a id="heart" href=""  style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 20px; height: 20px; font-size: 20px; background-image: url(http://localhost:1268/Selecciona/IMG/heart_enabled.png); background-repeat: no-repeat;"></a>

<a id="heart" href="" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 20px; height: 20px; font-size: 20px; background-image: url(http://localhost:1268/Selecciona/IMG/heart_disabled.png); background-repeat: no-repeat;"></a>
```

Can it possible in jQuery?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/css

Comment: Simply use css(), `$('a').css('background-image')`

Comment: Also ID must be unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('a').each(function(){
    // check if the image source contains the word 'enabled'
    var bgEnabled = $(this).css('background-image').indexOf('enabled') !== -1;
    
    alert('<a> #' + $(this).index() + ' is ' + (bgEnabled ? 'enabled' : 'disabled'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a class="heart" href="" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 20px; height: 20px; font-size: 20px; background-image: url(http://localhost:1268/Selecciona/IMG/heart_disabled.png); background-repeat: no-repeat;"></a>

<a class="heart" href=""  style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 20px; height: 20px; font-size: 20px; background-image: url(http://localhost:1268/Selecciona/IMG/heart_enabled.png); background-repeat: no-repeat;"></a>

<a class="heart" href="" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 20px; height: 20px; font-size: 20px; background-image: url(http://localhost:1268/Selecciona/IMG/heart_disabled.png); background-repeat: no-repeat;"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#heart").css('background-image');
```

or use js

```
alert(document.getElementById("diva").style.backgroundImage);
//the result of this is url("http://localhost:1268/Selecciona/IMG/heart_disabled.png");

//to show only the url, just substring it like this
url= document.getElementById("diva").style.backgroundImage;
alert(url.substring(4, url.length-1));
// and the result is http://localhost:1268/Selecciona/IMG/heart_disabled.png
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a combination of `.filter()` with the `.css()`:

```js
$("a").filter(function() {
    return $(this).css("background-image").indexOf('enabled') > 0;
}).css("border", "1px solid blue");

/* Or the other way round... */

$("a").filter(function() {
    return $(this).css("background-image").indexOf('disabled') > 0;
}).css("border", "1px solid red");
```

```css
a { background-color: #ccc; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="heart1" href="" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 20px; height: 20px; font-size: 20px; background-image: url(http://localhost:1268/Selecciona/IMG/heart_disabled.png); background-repeat: no-repeat;"></a>
<a id="heart2" href=""  style="position: absolute; left: 50px; top: 0px; width: 20px; height: 20px; font-size: 20px; background-image: url(http://localhost:1268/Selecciona/IMG/heart_enabled.png); background-repeat: no-repeat;"></a>
<a id="heart3" href="" style="position: absolute; left: 100px; top: 0px; width: 20px; height: 20px; font-size: 20px; background-image: url(http://localhost:1268/Selecciona/IMG/heart_disabled.png); background-repeat: no-repeat;"></a>
```